# how to pass location to selenium_driver.save_screenshot("test.png") in AWS Lambda? Unable to save screenshots from aws lambda

Tags: python, selenium, aws-lambda

I am trying to write an AWS Lambda function which will take the screenshot of the url passed in python. However I am not able to find the way to be directly download those image to either to local system or to upload them in s3.

I'm using selenium with headless chrome and after taking screenshot using driver.save_screenshot("test.png") (which works locally and saves the images in the location of the code) , lambda function is giving error.

Please see my code attached below!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("Starting google.com")
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/bin/headless-chromium"
    print("reaching here")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    page_data = ""
    if 'url' in event.keys():
        driver.get(event['url'])
        page_data = driver.page_source # working fine till here
        print(page_data)
        driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png") #error here

    driver.close()
    return page_data
```

Comment: What error does _lambda function_ shows?

Comment: It was throwing an error that image should be saved in png or something like that...anyway it has been solved now.

Comment: hey how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to get the image as base 64 and store in DynamoDB..

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
```